# How do I fill a HashMap<Long, Long> using a Stream in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, collectors

I want to fill a `HashMap<Long, Long>` using a Stream in Java. However, I am not getting it right. I hope someone can help.

I was thinking along these lines:

```
HashMap<Long, Long>  mapLongs = LongStream
    .rangeClosed(1, 10)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> getSquare(x)));
```

where `getSquare` is a simple function that returns the square, e.g.:

```
long getSquare(long x) {
    return x * x;
}
```

However, I get an error saying that `getSquare()` cannot be applied to an Object. When I try to cast x to an object, I get an error that:

> no instance(s) of type variable(s) A, K, T, U exist so that Collector> conforms to Supplier

Bottom line: I am stuck.

Also (obviously), I am trying to do something more complex than filling a Map with square values...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure your stream is [`boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/LongStream.html#boxed()).

```
Map<Long, Long> mapLongs = LongStream  // programming to interface 'Map'
        .rangeClosed(1, 10)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> getSquare(x))); // can use method reference as well
```